# Facebook Debugger doesn't see my Open Graph code

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-debugger

I cannot figure out why Facebook Debugger only sometimes sees my open graph code. Here is a page where it CAN see my code: https://buckscountyalive.com/articles/railroad-attractions.cfm
My code:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Hop Aboard a Vintage Railroad" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://buckscountyalive.com/articles/railroad-attractions.cfm" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://buckscountyalive.com/facebook/trains.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Take a ride through time on these three tourist-friendly railroads!" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="HidingForThisPost" />
```

Here's a page where it doesn't see my code: https://buckscountyalive.com/advertise/shop-local-gift-guide.cfm
My code:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Get your products in our local Holiday Gift Guide" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://buckscountyalive.com/advertise/shop-local-gift-guide.cfm" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://buckscountyalive.com/facebook/giftguide.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Reach customers in Bucks, Montgomery, Lehigh & Hunterdon" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="HidingForThisPost" />
```

What's interesting is that if I use HootSuite to create a Facebook post, it sees all of my open graph code and posts it beautifully on Facebook. HOWEVER, if someone then tries to SHARE that post, the open graph code is lost. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Looking at Facebook’s results for what its [scrapper sees](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fbuckscountyalive.com%2Fadvertise%2Fshop-local-gift-guide.cfm) for the local gift guide page, Facebook is stopping after line 32 in your head section (before any of the Open Graph information). I loaded your URL into Google’s old schema checker and the W3 Validator, and both stop after the same line. You could try opening the file in your editor and make sure there’s nothing after the tag (no space or strange character) and then reupload the file to your server.

Comment: Thanks, Rich. I found the trigger but it's not an html coding issue, it's a piece of programming, but it makes absolutely no sense. We know how to circumvent for now. Thanks for responding!